# Akka Actor preStart() & postStop() methods behaviors?

Tags: scala, akka

Says if I have an Actor for database accessing, an Actor is a singleton instance to handle all clients, or multiple instances for multiple clients? The Actor `preStart()` and `postStop()` methods are called only once for all instances? Or will be called when each new Actor instance is created? Is it good to put database initialisation code inside `preStart()`, and connection returning code inside `postStop()`?

Thanks

Comment: everytime you spawn a new actor from your actor class which inherits `Actor` `preXX` functions will be called. So, it is not a singleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of like asking if an object is a singleton. If you only ever create one of the database Actor it will behave as a singleton, but in general Actors are *not* singletons.

Even if you did just create one, you still need to think about when it might be restarted by the actor system or supervisor.

[Update]

The lifecycle methods are called for every Actor - they are independent entities.

If you are creating an Actor to handle database requests / data access I'd probably have a single Actor that has singleton semantics, but internally it could create and supervise as many or as few Actors that actually deal with the database calls. This would allow you to handle the initialisation and cleanup of the database in a single place (the top level Actor), and allow you to scale internally (if needed) by creating more Actors to handle requests and supervise them to properly handle errors.

As a side note, there's probably plenty of prior art in this scenario so I'd recommend doing a bit of research into how this is handled by others. You should also see how the database driver itself handles threading as you might just be building lots of accidental complexity

Comment: I modified my question, however, now I know Actors are not singleton, therefore I can not put my database initialisation in `preStart()`, database closing in `postStop()`.